# F# Test if element is in list using List.Fold

Tags: lambda, f#, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a function that takes a list and an element to look for in that list and returns true if the element is in the list and false otherwise. I want to use List.Fold to make the function much shorter. Right now it looks like this

```
let isInList(elementToFind, listToCheck) = 
    List.fold(fun(a, b) -> a=elementToFind or b), false, listToCheck;
```

However, I'm getting a syntax error at a=elementToFind or b saying that the expression was expected to have 'a -> 'b * 'c but has bool. I'm pretty new to F# and functional programming in general so any help I could get here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this using List.fold as follows:

```
let isInList elementToFind listToCheck = 
    List.fold(fun acc x -> acc || x = elementToFind) false listToCheck
```

Example:

```
let x = [1;2;2;3]
let y = 4
let z = 2

isInList y x |> printfn "%A"
isInList z x |> printfn "%A"
```

Print:

```
false
true
```

Link:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6swKR5

[Read more about List.fold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353894.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Way too many parenthesis and comas in your code.

To declare a function that takes 2 parameters you should use

```
let f param1 param2 = ...
```

No parenthesis, no comas. If you define a function as

```
let f2 (param1, param2) = ...
```

you define a function that takes 1 argument, and this argument is a 2-element tuple.

Removing all comas and almost all parenthesis from the code will leave one more error - the parameters of the function you pass to `List.fold` are in wrong order.

```
let isInList elementToFind listToCheck = 
    List.fold(fun acc elem -> elem=elementToFind || acc) false listToCheck
```

You should also check the documentation of the [List module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353738.aspx). There are many useful functions there, for example [`List.exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370309.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When performance is needed you better use tryFind, because fold is non-short-circuit.
That means if the list is 1 Mio. elements long and the first element is searched, the fold runs until the end of the list.

```
let isInList elementToFind listToCheck = 
    List.tryFind ((=) elementToFind) listToCheck

let x = [1;2;2;3]
let y = 4
let z = 2

isInList y x |> printfn "%A"    // None    
isInList z x |> printfn "%A"    // Some 2
```

Comment: As said by Jakub Lortz ; `List.exists` is a better choice then tryFind regarding the objective (knowing if it's there **only**) and has the same short-circuiting properties